# CUPS: How to troubleshoot "No printers found" condition?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, printing, cups

If I point my browser to `http://localhost:631/admin` and click on the <kbd>Find New Printers</kbd> button, the page that comes up reports

```
No printers found.
```

My (wired, wide-area) internet connection works fine (I'm posting this question through it), and I know that there are many printers on my network, including a couple that I can see from my desk.

**How can I troubleshoot this problem systematically?**

- what specific logs should I be examining for this?
- are there printing-specific kernel modules that should be loaded before available printers can be detected?
- anything else I should be looking at?

---

FWIW, I'm using

```
% uname -ar
Linux myhost 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u3 (2017-08-06) x86_64 \
GNU/Linux
```

...and have the following CUPS-related packages installed:

```
% dpkg-query -l | grep -i cups
ii  cups            2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - P
ii  cups-browsed    1.11.6-3     amd64        OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - cups-br
ii  cups-bsd        2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - B
ii  cups-client     2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - c
ii  cups-common     2.2.1-8      all          Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - c
ii  cups-core-drive 2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - P
ii  cups-daemon     2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - d
ii  cups-filters    1.11.6-3     amd64        OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Main Pa
ii  cups-filters-co 1.11.6-3     amd64        OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - PPD-les
ii  cups-ppdc       2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - P
ii  cups-server-com 2.2.1-8      all          Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - s
ii  libcups2:amd64  2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - C
ii  libcupscgi1:amd 2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - C
ii  libcupsfilters1 1.11.6-3     amd64        OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Shared 
ii  libcupsimage2:a 2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - R
ii  libcupsmime1:am 2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - M
ii  libcupsppdc1:am 2.2.1-8      amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - P
ii  libfontembed1:a 1.11.6-3     amd64        OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Font Em
ii  printer-driver- 5.2.11-1+b2  amd64        printer drivers for CUPS
```

(In fact, I installed the `task-print-server` meta package.)

Comment: the fact that there are many printers nearby doesn't mean much. they could be in separate subnet which your machine doesn't have a route to. I assume you are at work. Can you get the ip off nearest printer and try to ping it from your computer? is it reachable?

Comment: @Gnudiff: good points; yes, I can ping the nearest printer from the host in question.

Comment: local printer auto discovery relies on `mdns` which is provided by avahi. Check if you can `avahi-browse -a` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be nothing wrong with the printers or CUPS, but the printers may not advertise themselves or maybe the advertising protocol is disabled in switches/routers.

Your best bet is to try to Add Printer instead of Find, and if it is not found in Add printer list either, try to add it via "Other printers" and specify protocol and IP by hand -- if this works, it will mean that the main problem is printer discovery only.

Protocols may vary, but my best experience with HP printers and CUPS has been ipp, see [my own answer to my question at Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/853661/7747)

Note that your sysadmin, unless that is you, may have shared printers via Windows Print Server or CUPS already, possibly using non-IP or non-advertising protocol, and may expect everyone to use printers via Printserver shares for accounting and other purposes. Unless you are certain of what you are doing, your best bet is to resolve this via sysadmin.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer led me to the source of the problem.  It turns out that, *only after I clicked on `Add Printer`* was I prompted for authentication (i.e. root password), and once I gave it, `Find New Printers` began showing a non-empty list of printers.

Comment: @kjo Ok, I assumed you were already in admin mode. Note that eg on Ubuntu, you can add any user to lpadmin group and should be able to use that user and pass for cups administration instead of root.

Comment: Five years later, it is still like that and there is no obvious way to get to the "admin mode" except artificially going to `Add Printer`. If someone goes to `Find New Printers` directly, he is told that no printers can be found and no way to get to the admin mode and he has no  clue that such a mode even exists. At the least, this is the case with Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: Continuing ... It's related to the fact that `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` as `Require user @SYSTEM` for `Location /admin/conf` but not for `Location /admin` .